# having problems with .append()

Tags: jquery, html, facebook

I am getting a facebook graph api response and then trying to append it to a div on my html page.

The data returned comes in the format of

```
{
  "posts": {
    "data": [
      {
        "message": "hello and welcome to my fb page",
        "permalink_url": "https://www.facebook.com/{Page-id}/posts/1",
        "created_time": "2017-01-02T03:01:39+0000",
        "id": "784985445000793_689793694519968"
      }
    ],
    "paging": {
      "previous": "https://graph.facebook.com/v2.8/684985445000793/posts?fields=message,permalink_url,created_time&since=1483326099&access_token=EAACEdEose0cBAODD91oYj3HlLZCffFtMaZBkT3jCsGV6a1vwXgoy77zVcemkH1ibR0Q6ZB62ARZCQjezuZCGkwPbWy17AUpQ7IA7MqgFRuBhQuM1k3Qj497stZCYTwHHmszLQf9Oc3dIrAZBsNKvjHm1pcmetF3r4dOFNEJfY4pyOrqahcYxnaq&limit=25&__paging_token=enc_AdBtPTrNppu8xpLcnSYGmdAnZBZCxHeNQVZCZAXf6ptMRsuGo8rUjJOB7OvhM3o7pa8ERb0WHr5xkEOm4P3ysEBlKeyRA8k8qHsOaF4Eguw0WcLhSAZDZD&__previous=1",
      "next": "https://graph.facebook.com/v2.8/684985445000793/posts?fields=message,permalink_url,created_time&access_token=EAACEdEose0cBAODD91oYj3HlLZCffFtMaZBkT3jCsGV6a1vwXgoy77zVcemkH1ibR0Q6ZB62ARZCQjezuZCGkwPbWy17AUpQ7IA7MqgFRuBhQuM1k3Qj497stZCYTwHHmszLQf9Oc3dIrAZBsNKvjHm1pcmetF3r4dOFNEJfY4pyOrqahcYxnaq&limit=25&until=1483326099&__paging_token=enc_AdBtPTrNppu8xpLcnSYGmdAnZBZCxHeNQVZCZAXf6ptMRsuGo8rUjJOB7OvhM3o7pa8ERb0WHr5xkEOm4P3ysEBlKeyRA8k8qHsOaF4Eguw0WcLhSAZDZD"
    }
  },
  "id": "684985445000793"
}
```

so basically there are object from my knowledge is data.posts[i].objectname

ie. for message of post 1 would be data.posts[1].message

my code is as follows and i believe i am doing something wrong in my for loops, but i cannot figure out how to get around it, i basically need to iterate through the data.posts not just data will only contain the posts so no need to iterate through data, just the posts within data.

my current code is as follows:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: 'proxy.php',
                data: {graphUrl: 'https://graph.facebook.com/{My-Page-ID}?fields=posts{message,permalink_url,created_time}'}, 
                timeout:  timeout,
                error: load_error,
                success: function (postinf) {
                    for (var i = 0; i < postinf.length; i++){
                        function(posts) {
                            for (var ii = 0; ii < posts.length; ii++){
                                var post = postinf.posts[ii].message;
                                var postlnk = postinf.posts[ii].permalink_url;
                                var time = postinf.posts[ii].created_time;
                                $('#fb-feed').html('<a href="' + postlnk + '">' + post + '<br /> <br />@' + time + '<br /> <br />');
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    };
                    console.log(out);
                }
            });

        });
    });
</script>
```

I am not getting any errors on proxy.php so I do believe that it is within this .HTML page and not the php script.

but just incase, here is the php

```
<?php
// always add this header to ensure the JSON is output in the correct format
header("Expires: Mon, 26 Jul 1997 05:00:00 GMT");
header("Cache-Control: no-cache");
header("Pragma: no-cache");
header('Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8'); 

$graphUrl = $_POST['graphUrl'];
if ($graphUrl == "") {
    $graphUrl = "https://graph.facebook.com/facebook/feed?fields=posts{message,permalink_url,created_time}";
}

//App Info, needed for Auth
$app_id = "MY-APP-ID";
$app_secret = "MY-APP-SECRET";

//retrieve auth token
$authToken = fetchUrl("https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?type=client_cred&client_id={$app_id}&client_secret={$app_secret}");

//Echo back json to read client side.
echo fetchUrl("{$graphUrl}&access_token={$authToken}");

function fetchUrl($url){
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 20);
    $retData = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch); 
    return $retData;
}
?>
```

Thanks in advance to whomever is able to help me solve this issue.

Comment: This isn't the immediate problem you're having, but you might have better luck in general by using the JavaScript and PHP SDKs for the Facebook Graph API.  If your application is entirely client-side, the JS SDK is all you need.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to iterate throw `postinf.posts.data.length` like that:

```
for (var i = 0; i < postinf.posts.data.length; i++){
    var post = postinf.posts.data[i].message;
    var postlnk = postinf.posts.data[i].permalink_url;
    var time = postinf.posts.data[i].created_time;
}
```

Below is a running example:

```js
var postinf = {
  "posts": {
    "data": [
      {
        "message": "hello and welcome to my fb page",
        "permalink_url": "https://www.facebook.com/{Page-id}/posts/1",
        "created_time": "2017-01-02T03:01:39+0000",
        "id": "784985445000793_689793694519968"
      }
    ],
    "paging": {
      "previous": "https://graph.facebook.com/v2.8/684985445000793/posts?fields=message,permalink_url,created_time&since=1483326099&access_token=EAACEdEose0cBAODD91oYj3HlLZCffFtMaZBkT3jCsGV6a1vwXgoy77zVcemkH1ibR0Q6ZB62ARZCQjezuZCGkwPbWy17AUpQ7IA7MqgFRuBhQuM1k3Qj497stZCYTwHHmszLQf9Oc3dIrAZBsNKvjHm1pcmetF3r4dOFNEJfY4pyOrqahcYxnaq&limit=25&__paging_token=enc_AdBtPTrNppu8xpLcnSYGmdAnZBZCxHeNQVZCZAXf6ptMRsuGo8rUjJOB7OvhM3o7pa8ERb0WHr5xkEOm4P3ysEBlKeyRA8k8qHsOaF4Eguw0WcLhSAZDZD&__previous=1",
      "next": "https://graph.facebook.com/v2.8/684985445000793/posts?fields=message,permalink_url,created_time&access_token=EAACEdEose0cBAODD91oYj3HlLZCffFtMaZBkT3jCsGV6a1vwXgoy77zVcemkH1ibR0Q6ZB62ARZCQjezuZCGkwPbWy17AUpQ7IA7MqgFRuBhQuM1k3Qj497stZCYTwHHmszLQf9Oc3dIrAZBsNKvjHm1pcmetF3r4dOFNEJfY4pyOrqahcYxnaq&limit=25&until=1483326099&__paging_token=enc_AdBtPTrNppu8xpLcnSYGmdAnZBZCxHeNQVZCZAXf6ptMRsuGo8rUjJOB7OvhM3o7pa8ERb0WHr5xkEOm4P3ysEBlKeyRA8k8qHsOaF4Eguw0WcLhSAZDZD"
    }
  },
  "id": "684985445000793"
};
for (var i = 0; i < postinf.posts.data.length; i++){
 var post = postinf.posts.data[i].message;
    var postlnk = postinf.posts.data[i].permalink_url;
    var time = postinf.posts.data[i].created_time;
    $('#fb-feed').html('<a href="' + postlnk + '">' + post + '<br /> <br />@' + time + '<br /> <br />');
  console.log("post:", post);
  console.log("postlnk:", postlnk);
  console.log("time:", time);
}
```

```css
#fb-feed{
 width: 100%;
  background-color: #ea0;
  font-weight: color;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="fb-feed"></div>
```

Does that help?

Comment: Perfect the for loops are fixed. The example remove my function to display the results in my div though

Comment: You can just uncomment the jQuery line which append your div with new content

Comment: I just updated my running code answer to update your div

Comment: @MichaelDugas don't forget to mark my answer as "answered"

Comment: it is not populating my div tag :(

Comment: I was able to get it to work using the run code snippet here, so clearly i have errors in my coding (PROBABLY in my .php file as when i use it i am not seeming to get any data :( sigh)

Comment: @AlaEddineJEBALI Don't concatenate arbitrary data into HTML.  It will lead to invalid HTML and may even be a security issue.  Use `$('<a>').attr('href', url);` instead of `'<a href="' + url + '">'`.